# Generate a sequence of date from arrival_dt till departure_dt using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I need help with the Oracle SQL logic to generate the sequence of dates starting from arrival_dt till depature_dt 
Please find the current data set

```
prop_id blk_id  arrival_dt  departure_dt    num_stay    start_dt    day_num star_num    booking_num create_dt   room_type   revenue room_num    adults
353     3669281  18-Jun-15  21-Jun-15          1        18-Jun-15   1        579071315  21803       13-Jul-15   W             314   2009          1
353     3669281  18-Jun-15  21-Jun-15          1        19-Jun-15   2        579071315  21803       13-Jul-15   W             314   2009          1
353     3669281  18-Jun-15  21-Jun-15          1        19-Jun-15   3        579071315  21803       13-Jul-15   W             314   2009          1
```

I want start_dt column having the values as 18-jun-15, 19-jun-15 and 20-jun-15

Desired Output

```
prop_id blk_id  arrival_dt  departure_dt    num_stay    start_dt    day_num star_num    booking_num create_dt   room_type   revenue room_num    adults
    353     3669281  18-Jun-15  21-Jun-15          1        18-Jun-15   1        579071315  21803       13-Jul-15   W             314   2009          1
    353     3669281  18-Jun-15  21-Jun-15          1        19-Jun-15   2        579071315  21803       13-Jul-15   W             314   2009          1
    353     3669281  18-Jun-15  21-Jun-15          1        20-Jun-15   3        579071315  21803       13-Jul-15   W             314   2009          1
```

The query that I'm using is complex and it is using multiple tables to fetch the data and it would confuse more, I need a way so that with the given arrival_dt and departure_dt, it should generate the sequence of dates within the arrival_dt and departure_dt range so that I can integrate it to the query that I'm already using it.

In the above mentioned example, arrival_dt is 18-jun-2015 and departure_dt is 21-jun-2015 and I want the start_dt in a sequence starting from arrival_dt till departure_dt which would be 18-jun-2015, 19-jun-2015 and 20-jun-2015

Comment: Can you please exaplain in more detail? start_dt already has a date value now. Do you want it to have a list of dates or do you want to have multiple rows? Please show your table structure, your attempted query (I assume you have attempted *something*) and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

For this dataset `day_num` column appears to be a sequence starting from 1, so you can use this expression: `arrival_dt + day_num - 1 As new_date` to calculate a sequence of dates:

```
SELECT t.*, arrival_dt + day_num - 1 As new_date
FROM table1 t
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c0c33/1

---

Generally the following query can be used to generate a sequence of values from 1 to x:

```
SELECT level as sequence FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= x
```

For example if we want to generate numbers from 1 to 15:

```
SELECT LEVEL as sequence FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 15
```

or when a sequence -5, -4, -3,  ...., 3, 4, 5 is needed:

```
SELECT LEVEL - 6 as sequence FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5 - ( -6 )
;
```

If you want to create a sequence of dates from one date to another, calculate a number of days between these two dates - just substract these two dates. For example when the start date is: 2015-05-01 and the end date is 2015-05-05, the query is:

```
SELECT LEVEL + to_date('2015-05-01','yyyy-mm-dd') - 1 As new_date
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 
                    + to_date('2015-05-05','yyyy-mm-dd') 
                    - to_date('2015-05-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c0c33/7

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a hierarchical query to generate the days as noted in other responses, or you can use a recursive query as in this simplified example:

```
with sample_data(id, arrival_dt, departure_dt) as (
  select 1, date '2015-06-18', date '2015-06-21' from dual union all
  select 2, date '2015-07-27', date '2015-08-01' from dual
)
, t1(id, arrival_dt, departure_dt, start_dt, day_num) as (
  select id, arrival_dt, departure_dt, arrival_dt, 1 from sample_data
  union all
  select id, arrival_dt, departure_dt, start_dt+1, day_num+1 from t1
   where start_dt+1 < departure_dt
)
select * from t1 order by id, day_num;

        ID ARRIVAL_DT  DEPARTURE_DT START_DT       DAY_NUM
---------- ----------- ------------ ----------- ----------
         1 18-JUN-2015 21-JUN-2015  18-JUN-2015          1
         1 18-JUN-2015 21-JUN-2015  19-JUN-2015          2
         1 18-JUN-2015 21-JUN-2015  20-JUN-2015          3
         2 27-JUL-2015 01-AUG-2015  27-JUL-2015          1
         2 27-JUL-2015 01-AUG-2015  28-JUL-2015          2
         2 27-JUL-2015 01-AUG-2015  29-JUL-2015          3
         2 27-JUL-2015 01-AUG-2015  30-JUL-2015          4
         2 27-JUL-2015 01-AUG-2015  31-JUL-2015          5
```

If you want the last `START_DT` generated to match the `DEPARTURE_DT` then change the `WHERE` clause in to one of the following:

```
where state_dt < departure_dt
```

or

```
where state_dt+1 <= departure_dt
```